# How to read an encrypted directory file using different IIS user

Tags: windows, web-services, encryption, public-key-encryption

I would like to read/access a file which from an encrypted  directory using IIS on browser?

Comment: just new to that so im trying to access some encrypted .bin files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have specific files, you should be able to add the IIS user as an authorized user: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457007.aspx

On my machine the IIS user has an EFS certificate already, but I could not find any documentation about whether that is always the case.